# Sprint boot 2.0.5 @ConfigurationProperties don't populate lists if properties are not in Spring boot application file

Tags: spring-boot

Every properties, inclusive list, are populated right when they are set up in application.yml, otherwise single properties are right although list is empty if I create a new file and I target it through **@PropertySource**

***application.yml***

```
name: test-YAML3
environment: test
servers: 
    - www.abc.test.com
    - www.xyz.test.com
```

***custom.yml***

```
name: test-YAML2
environment: test
servers: 
    - www.abc.test.com
    - www.xyz.test.com
```

***@ConfigurationProperties***

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource( value = "classpath:application.yml")
//@PropertySource( value = "classpath:custom.yml")
@Validated
@Getter @Setter
public class ServerProperties 
{
      private String name;
      private String environment;
      private List<String> servers = new ArrayList();
}
```

Below show populated list because I use *application.yml*

[image]

Below show missing list because I set up *custom.yml*

[image]

Any suggestions? Am I missing anything? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@PropertySource` does not suppport YAML so your YAML is being read as a properties file. It works when you use `application.yml`, not because of your `@PropertySource`, but because Spring Boot will read `application.yml` by default and with no further configuration.

If you want to use a name other than `application`, you can use `spring.config.name` to change it. For example:

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.config.name=custom
```

There’s more information available in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Comment: great. Thanks for this info